# Resizing content with responsive image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am using a banner image which will resize depending on the width of the screen. I want the other content which overlays the image and also appears under the image to reduce it's top margin as the image changes size. How should I do this?

```css
header {
  background-color: #02a5da;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f7f7f7;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .tpLogin {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.navBar {
  background-color: #02a5da;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 45px;
}

.navLink {
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}


/*Home*/

.tpLogin {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
  .tpLogin {
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  .homeInfo {
    margin-top: 200px;
  }
}

#username,
#password {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#btnSubmit {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

.login {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -105px;
}

.homeIcons {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.homeInfo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.homeInfoHeading {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.homeInfoText {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .textSplit {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #02a5da;
  }
  .iconPadding {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
}

.last {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pure-release-1.0.0/grids-responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navBar pure-u-5-5">
    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-6-24"></div>
      <a class="active pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='index.html'>
        <div class="navText">Home</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='about.html'>
        <div class="navText">About Me</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='service.html'>
        <div class="navText">Service</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='contact.html'>
        <div class="navText">Contact</div>
      </a>
      <div class="pure-u-6-24"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <img class="banner" src="https://s14.postimg.cc/pew1gpjgh/home2.jpg" />

  <div class="tpLogin">
    <h2>Already a Member?</h2>
    <form name="login" class="login" method="POST" action="https://home.trainingpeaks.com/login">
      <div class="validation">
      </div>
      <input class="pure-u-5-5" id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required>
      <input class="pure-u-5-5" id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" required>
      <input class="pure-u-5-5 pure-button" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" type="submit" class="buttonBlue1" value="Login" tabindex="3">
    </form>
    <h3><a href="service.html">How do I become a member?</a></h3>
  </div>

  <div class="homeInfo pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
      <i class="fas fa-bullhorn homeIcons"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Service</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText textSplit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
      <i class="fas fa-cogs homeIcons iconPadding"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Software</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText textSplit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3 last">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle homeIcons iconPadding"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Goal</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have created a JS Fiddle so you can see what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/xp7b8k8p/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make it so you do not absolutely position your image.  Absolute positioning shouldn't really be used for layout purposes - it's for when you want to remove something from the natural flow of the document (eg the login box).

With that in mind, I have changed your styles:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
  .tpLogin {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}

.navBar {
  background-color: #02a5da;
  text-align: center;
  height: 45px;
}

.navLink {
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
}


/*Home*/

.tpLogin {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#username,
#password {
  max-width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

#btnSubmit {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: #404040;
  color: #f7f7f7;
}

.login {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.banner-wrapper {
  position:relative;
}

.homeIcons {
  font-size: 40px;
}

.homeInfo {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

.homeInfoHeading {
  font-size: 26px;
}

.homeInfoText {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.last {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@1.0.0/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-nn4HPE8lTHyVtfCBi5yW9d20FjT8BJwUXyWZT9InLYax14RDjBj46LmSztkmNP9w" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pure-release-1.0.0/grids-responsive.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="navBar pure-u-5-5">
    <div class="pure-g">
      <div class="pure-u-6-24"></div>
      <a class="active pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='index.html'>
        <div class="navText">Home</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='about.html'>
        <div class="navText">About Me</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='service.html'>
        <div class="navText">Service</div>
      </a>
      <a class="pure-u-3-24 navLink" href='contact.html'>
        <div class="navText">Contact</div>
      </a>
      <div class="pure-u-6-24"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="banner-wrapper">
    <img class="banner" src="https://s14.postimg.cc/pew1gpjgh/home2.jpg" />

    <div class="tpLogin">
      <h2>Already a Member?</h2>
      <form name="login" class="login" method="POST" action="https://home.trainingpeaks.com/login">
        <div class="validation">
        </div>
        <input class="pure-u-5-5" id="username" type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" required>
        <input class="pure-u-5-5" id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" required>
        <input class="pure-u-5-5 pure-button" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" type="submit" class="buttonBlue1" value="Login" tabindex="3">
      </form>
      <h3><a href="service.html">How do I become a member?</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="homeInfo pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
      <i class="fas fa-bullhorn homeIcons"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Service</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText textSplit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
      <i class="fas fa-cogs homeIcons iconPadding"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Software</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText textSplit">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3 last">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle homeIcons iconPadding"></i>
      <h2 class="homeInfoHeading">Goal</h2>
      <p class="homeInfoText">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam maximus erat eget elit mollis, vel congue sem gravida. Vivamus ipsum ex, blandit quis neque a, vulputate sagittis lacus. Ut nec luctus ante. Cras non est massa. Fusce malesuada libero
        orci, in feugiat odio imperdiet id. Ut gravida, libero ac iaculis vestibulum, libero felis semper libero.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks this works great. Is it possible to change the top margin of the login box as the width changes in order to keep it's position in the centre of the image vertically?

Comment: See update - put the banner and login box in a wrapper and then centre the login box

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you for your help.